# Function from a set to a ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, function-spaces

Let $A$ be a ring and $S$ be a set. Let $F(S,A)$ be the set of functions of the form $f: S \rightarrow A$. For all $f,g \in F(S,A)$ define $(f+g)(s)=f(s)+g(s)$, and $(fg)(s)=f(s)g(s)$.

Show that $F(S,A)$ is commutative if and only if $A$ is commutative.

Comment: How do you define the group structure on $F(S,A)$?

Comment: You also need $S \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: I wonder how one can ask such a (trivial) question without giving any thoughts about it. Reading complete proofs doesn't really improve your mathematical skills. That being said, I also always wonder why people (who should know it better) post complete proofs instead of providing hints of how to find a proof for oneself (often, a hint to look at the definitions should be enough).

Comment: @Martin - I have had the same thought many times before. I gave a hint in the comments, but there isn't anything more to hint at than looking at the definitions. So I decided to just spell it out so that the question can be closed and forgotten.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is commutative then for all $f,g\in F(S,A)$ and all $s\in S$ we have
$$(fg)(s)=f(s)g(s)=g(s)f(s)=(gf)(s),$$
which means that $fg=gf$, and hence $F(S,A)$ is commutative.

If $A$ is not commutative there exist $x,y\in A$ such that $xy\neq yx$. For the maps $c_x$ and $c_y$ mapping constantly to $x$ resp. $y$ it holds $c_xc_y\neq c_yc_x$, so $F(S,A)$ is not commutative if $S\neq\varnothing$.

EDIT (thanks to Paolo Capriotti):

If $S=\varnothing$ then $F(S,A)=\{\varnothing\}$ which is commutative, so the statement is false.